# Navbar active item color

Tags: css, navbar

Is it possible to give color to an active item of the navbar in ***CSS*** without using JS and jQuery? Actually, I want my navbar working smooth.

1. It is single page application.
2. I tried .classname a.active(className of ){backgroundcolor: green;} but it only work with only  with className active other remain in their position.

Comment: I tried .classname a.active(className of <a>){backgroundcolor: green;}   but it only work with only <a> with className active other remain in their position

Comment: Hi, it would be useful if you could add a bit more explanation to your question. For example, the info you gave in a comment makes it clearer what you want to do:" I mean instead of - $(document).ready(function () { $('ul.navbar-nav > li') .click(function (e) { $('ul.navbar-nav > li') .removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active'); }); }); is there any css code? "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this without using JS, but you need to have some structure in your HTML to make it possible.

For example, in this snippet each li element starts with an input element of type radio. All the li input elements are given the same name so they are grouped - meaning when one radio button is clicked it is checked and all the others are unchecked. Using CSS we can select the immediately following element which has the text in it and change its background color, or any other required styling, if its preceding input element is checked.

```css
.navbar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav li input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-nav li input:checked+* {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li><input type="radio" checked name="nav"><span>Item 1</span></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="nav"><span>Item 2</span></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="nav"><span>Item 3</span></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="nav"><span>Item 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Note that the input elements are given opacity 0 so they are still there but not visible, and they are made the same size and the same place as the item by being position absolute.

Comment: Nice solution to an otherwise unconventional request to a common situation. You could also wrap the text in a `label` element and associate it with the `input` using the `for` attribute on the `label` and a corresponding `id` attribute on the `input` - then you should be able to simply hide the `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you maybe mean either of those?

```
#nav li a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

or

```
#nav li a:active {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I mean instead of -  $(document).ready(function () {
  
            $('ul.navbar-nav > li')
                    .click(function (e) {
                $('ul.navbar-nav > li')
                    .removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });                                                is there any css code?

Comment: there is no way in CSS only to do it @hari